Nginx configuration files in docker
I have a server with the following docker-compose.yml:
version: "3"
services:
  frontend:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: staticfloat/nginx-certbot
    ports:
      - 80:80/tcp
      - 443:443/tcp
    environment:
      CERTBOT_EMAIL: softtimur@gmail.com
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/user.conf.d:ro
      - letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
  studio:
    image: bitnami/nginx:latest
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - ./build:/app
      - ./default.conf:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/default.conf:ro
      - ./configs/config.prod.js:/app/lib/config.js
    depends_on: 
    - frontend

volumes:
  letsencrypt:

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: studio

Additionally, there is a file conf.d/prod.conf for nginx configuration.
I did docker exec -it frontend_frontend_1 /bin/bash, I can see there are /etc/nginx/user.conf.d/prod.conf and /etc/nginx/conf.d/prod.conf which are identical. I understand that /etc/nginx/user.conf.d/prod.conf was mounted because of - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/user.conf.d:ro in docker-compose.yml, but why is there /etc/nginx/conf.d/prod.conf?
Does anyone know?


but why is there /etc/nginx/conf.d/prod.conf?

Because when you run the staticfloat/nginx-certbot image, it runs the script /scripts/entrypoint.sh, which runs this code (among other things):
template_user_configs() {
    SOURCE_DIR="${1-/etc/nginx/user.conf.d}"
    TARGET_DIR="${2-/etc/nginx/conf.d}"

    # envsubst needs dollar signs in front of all variable names
    DENV=$(echo ${ENVSUBST_VARS} | sed -E 's/\$*([^ ]+)/\$\1/g')

    echo "templating scripts from ${SOURCE_DIR} to ${TARGET_DIR}"
    echo "Substituting variables ${DENV}"

    if [ ! -d "$SOURCE_DIR" ]; then
        echo "no ${SOURCE_DIR}, nothing to do."
    else
        for conf in ${SOURCE_DIR}/*.conf; do
            echo " -> ${conf}"
            envsubst "${DENV}" <"${conf}" > "${TARGET_DIR}/$(basename ${conf})"
        done
    fi
}

That copies files from /etc/nginx/user.conf.d into /etc/nginx/conf.d while performing environment variable substitution.
